# Help with some set logic of $C$ contained in $A$, $B$ contained in $C$, What is $C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A=\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6,7\rbrace$ and $B=\lbrace 2,3,6,7\rbrace$. List all sets $C$ such that $C\subseteq A$ and $B\subseteq C$. Enter your answer as a list of sets separated by commas, e.g.: $\lbrace a\rbrace, \lbrace a,b\rbrace$.

I got:
$\lbrace 2,3,6,7\rbrace$ but I am not sure why that is incorrect.

Comment: For example, you miss $B\cup \{1\}$, …

Comment: If B is a subset of C then that means C HAS to contain at least 2,3,6,7.

Comment: $C$ verify $B\subseteq C\subseteq A$, so $C$ must contain the elements of $B$.

Comment: You got just one set. They ask "List *all* sets $C$.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of sets C is the set of subsets of A that each contain B as a subset.

So

(1) list all the subsets of A, that is generate the power set of A

(2) rule out all the sets than do not contain B as a subset

Note : all the subsets of A having strictly less elements than B, that is, having less that 4 elements, can be ruled out even without being examined.

[image]